# Updating Jira items from Jenkins Pipeline build: jiraIssueSelector doesn't find any issues

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

In freestyle Jenkins jobs, there is a post-build step called `"JIRA: Update relevant issues"`.  This job will add comments in the the appropriate JIRA tasks (based on commit messages) saying whether the build succeeded or failed.

[![JIRA: Update relevant issues][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBJVZ.png

I am wanting to do the same thing from a pipeline job.

As far as I can tell, there's nothing built-in that does all of that in one step like the post-build step for freestyle jobs does.

I *am* able to use the `jiraComment` pipeline step to add comments to Jira items, but I still need to figure out from the commit messages which Jira items need to be updated.

I am trying to use the `jiraIssueSelector` pipeline step to do that.

When I put the following in my Jenkinsfile:

```
    def issueKeys = jiraIssueSelector(issueSelector: [$class: 'DefaultIssueSelector'])    
    echo "${issueKeys.size()}"
```

And run it against a commit with the commit message `"DEVO-2398 DEVO-2399"`, it gives me the output

```
    [Pipeline] jiraIssueSelector
    [Pipeline] echo
    0
```

The `jiraIssueSelector` is not finding *any* jiraIssues in the commit message.

When I run a freestyle job with the `JIRA: Update relevant issues` post-build step against that same git commit, it finds both Jira issues.  I get the following output:

```
[JIRA] Updating issue DEVO-2399
[JIRA] Updating issue DEVO-2398
```

So my question is twofold:

1. Is there an easier way to replicate the functionality of the Jira post-build step in pipeline than by combining `jiraComment` and `jiraIssueSelector`?
2. Assuming that there is not, what am I doing wrong with `jiraIssueSelector`?  Why is it not finding any Jira issues in the commit message when there the Jira post-build step is able to find them just find them just fine?

Comment: So what's your globally configured pattern?

Comment: It is left blank, so it's using the default ([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+-[1-9][0-9]*)([^.]|\.[^0-9]|\.$|$)

Comment: Should work. Please report an issue for Jira plugin.

Comment: Issue reported.

Comment: Thanks. If you find it useful please link it here as well.

Comment: Here's the bug report: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58628

Comment: And the bug was closed that it cannot be reproduced... and here I am trying to do the same thing as OP but can't find any tutorials or documentation on how to do it

Comment: The bug also has a comment about what I was doing wrong.  I haven't had a chance to test it, though, as I am no longer using Jenkins.